# digitalRead() Arduino, will it wait for a key to be pressed?

Tags: arduino-uno

This is my Arduino code:

```
void loop()
{
 state=digitalRead(2);
  if(state==HIGH)
  {
    update();
  }
}
```

I want the function **update()** to be called if the button in pin2 is pressed.
Will 'state=digitalRead(2)' this statement wait for the key press? If no, what do you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

Of course not. This function will return the **current state** of that pin immediately.

Comment: So what do you suggest?

Comment: Check it in a loop.  But first read about contact bounce, if you plan to be waiting for this event more than once in any small amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

This code can replace all your code through your function loop()

```
void setup()
{
  attachInterrupt(2, update, RISING);
}

void loop()
{

}

void update()
{
...
}
```

Comment: Possibly, as a very different design, but you are still missing a lot to implement the poster's current functional goal.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a while loop to wait for a button press:

```
while (!digitalRead(2)) {
delay(100);
}
```

So your script gets stuck in a loop and waits for a button press.